# MySQL foreign key not found even if it exists

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables 'open_invoices' and 'paid_invoices' with the below structures:

```
CREATE TABLE `open_invoices` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unique_identifier` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `insert_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `cust_nbr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_nbr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `future_letter` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_total` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_payments` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `record_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `terms_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `due_date` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `discount_date` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `orig_disc_avail` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `cust_po` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_date` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `check_no` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `last_pay_date` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `as_of_date` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `as_of_time` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `remaining` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_identifier` (`unique_identifier`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `paid_invoices` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date_change` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `invoice_date` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    `unique_identifier` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `amount_paid` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
    `amount_left` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
    `payment_type` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    `last4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `transac_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `customer_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `payment_P_F` varchar(1) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (unique_identifier)
    REFERENCES open_invoices (unique_identifier) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm trying to insert a row in 'paid_invoices' like below:

```
INSERT INTO `paid_invoices` (`invoice_date`, `unique_identifier`, `amount_paid`, `amount_left`, `payment_type`, `last4`, `transac_id`, `customer_id`, `payment_P_F`) VALUES ('07/19/18', '126_89948_2576', 0, '37.45', '', '', '', '13776', 'P')
```

I get the below error:

```
Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`accounts_receivables`.`paid_invoices`, CONSTRAINT `paid_invoices_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`unique_identifier`) REFERENCES `open_invoices` (`unique_identifier`))

INSERT INTO `paid_invoices` (`invoice_date`, `unique_identifier`, `amount_paid`, `amount_left`, `payment_type`, `last4`, `transac_id`, `customer_id`, `payment_P_F`) VALUES ('07/19/18', '126_89948_2576', 0, '37.45', '', '', '', '13776', 'P')
```

If I search on google, it says that the foreign key 126_89948_2576 was not found in the table 'open_invoices'.

When I do `SELECT * FROM` open_invoices `WHERE id = 2576` I see the row with the foreign key 126_89948_2576 as shown in the picture below :
[![query 1][1]][1]
but when I do this query `SELECT * FROM` open_invoices `WHERE unique_identifier = '126_89948_2576'`  I get no result see capture below:

[![query 2][2]][2]

I'm sure there is no extra blank space in the value saved for foreign key 126_89948_2576.

What is going on please? Is there a bug in the version of MySQL I'm using?

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.40 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
```

Thanks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2QDX.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9Fz5.png

Comment: May be you are using `_` dividers but there `-` are used, between numbers in unique_identifier.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are using wrong divider symbols, "_" instead of "-" in your query. Try `unique_identifier = '126-89948-2576'`

Comment: Dammmm it. I was focused on the queries, my bad. Thanks you are right.

Comment: I sense a face-palm coming on :). D'oh!

Comment: Glad to be helpful. These things happen.

Answer (score 1):

Because the underscore _ is a wildcard like the percent %, except that it only looks for one character.

SQL pattern matching enables you to use "_" to match any single character and "%" to match an arbitrary number of characters (including zero characters).

you can use

**SELECT * FROM open_invoices WHERE unique_identifier like '%126\_89948\_2576%'**

Comment: Yes, that would help. Updated the answer.